# Woocommerce - different/individual page.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i want to use a different navigation and some other individual codes for all WooCommerce pages.

For  `archive-product.php` or `content-single-product.php` this is no problem. I used them in my themechild (theme-chiild/woocommerce). But for pages like cart or checkout its not working.

Is it possible to use a different `page.php` for all WooCommerce pages?

Answer (score 1):

Cart and Checkout by default use your default page.php and just use a shortcode to generate the page content.

So you have a few options.

- Modify page.php to check if it is cart/checkout
- Create a custom page template for both that modifies what you need
- Create a custom page template for each if you need different options on each

  - In Woocommerce > templates you do have cart/checkout templates as well

Depending on the level of customization. You may need to hook into those pages to add/remove what you need. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html